# cakephp persistent filter on tutorial jamesfairhurst

Tags: cakephp, filter, components

I have created a filter on my table following the tutorial:

http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/cakephp_filter_component/

Can anyone help me to find out a way to make the filters persistent
after pagination?

### Thanks a lot.

I have chose this component because I have the following problem with plugins.
I have just installed CakePhp in a new environment, Ubuntu 12.10.
The root directory is /var/www/cakephp.
I have a database which consists of three tables.
I have created a new project with the following commands:

```
#cd /var/www/cakephp
#cake bake project jobsv2
#cake bake db_config
#cake bake model all
#cake bake controller all
#cake bake view all
```

Now I want to add a Plugin called Filter.
I have copied it in /var/www/cakephp/jobsv2/plugins/Filter and I have
put the following line in the file /var/www/cakephp/jobsv2/config/bootstrap.php :

```
CakePlugin::load('Filter');
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'CakePlugin' not found in /var/www/cakephp/jobsv2/config/bootstrap.php on line 52
```

If I put the plugin in /var/wwww/cakephp/app/Plugin, the plugin is not 
recognized from CakePhp and I get the error "component not found".
Do you have any clue of why this happens?
Searching in the pligins I found this I like:

https://github.com/pedroelsner/filter_results

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off trying to use a more up to date component/plugin. You can search on [plugins.cakephp.org](http://plugins.cakephp.org).

Comment: I have choose this component because I have the following problems with plugins.

Comment: `CakePlugin` class is available since 2.x. In 1.x the plugins didn't use that class. So if your app is in 1.x pick the 1.x branch for a plugin.

Comment: The plugin I am using is for 2.x

Comment: Right but since you are getting an error for CakePlugin class your cakephp core is most likely 1.x not 2.x